# 'set' not declared? Adruino

Tags: processing

I have zero experience with programming adruino but I have to test these robots for my job. I was told this code drives the robots foreword. When I run this code I get the error that 'set' is not declared in this scope. Help? Or let me know if this isn't even the right question to ask. Those libraries at the top are also with me, but I'm unsure if I need to post them to solve this particular problem.

```java
#include <Lobotank.h>
#include <tank_Cwrap.h>

int temp_R=0;
int temp_L=0;
int c15=0;

void setup()
{
  enableDebug();
  //test sensors(1000);
  set  speed(125);
}

void loop()
{
  update sensors();
int pattern = 0;
long rndm = random(0,10);

  serial.println(rndm);
  //serial.println(temp_L);
  //serial.println(lf_left);
  //serial.println(lf_mleft);
  //serial.println(lf_mright);
  //serial.println(lf_right);

if (lf_left>= 500)
  pattern += 8;
if (lf_mleft >= 500)
  pattern += 4;
if (lf_mright >= 500)
  pattern += 2;
if (lf_right >= 500)
  pattern += 1;

switch (pattern)
{
  case 0:
    if (temp_R ==1)
      turnRight_hard();
    else
      turnAround_left()
    break;
  case 1:

  turnRight_slight();
  temp_R = 1;
break;


case 2:
      turnRight_slight();
      temp_R = 1;
    break;
  case 3:
    delay(25);
      turnRight_slight();
    break;
  case 6:
      forward();
      temp_R = 0;
      c15 = 0;
    break;
  case 7: //turn right
      turnRight_hard();
      temp_R = 1;
    break;
  case 8:
      turnleft_slight();
      temp_R = 0;
    break;
  case 12:
    delay(15);
      turnLeft_slight();
    break;
  case 14: //turn left
      turnLeft_hard();
    break;
  case 15:
    delay(25);
          if (rndm <= 5 && c15 <= 3)
            turnleft_hard();
      else 
        {
          if (rndm >= 6 && c15 <= 3)
            turnRight_hard();
      else 
        {
          if (c15 >= 5)
            turnRight_hard();
      else
        {
          if (c15>= 10)
      stop();
            }
          }
        }
      c15++;
      break;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look like valid syntax:

```java
set  speed(125);
```

This looks like a function call, but functions can't have spaces in them. Maybe you meant one of these:

```java
setspeed(125);
setSpeed(125);
set_speed(125);
```

Look in those `.h` files for a function similar to these, and make sure you call it with the correct name.

Comment: I see, thank you, it turned out to be the second one...There are some more errors but I'll try to solve them with the idea that they're supposed to be function calls in mind. Thanks.

Comment: @GeorgeMcFlying No problem. It looks like you've got similar issues with other functions. Just keep in mind that functions can't contain spaces, and make sure you spell them exactly the same. If you get stuck, feel free to post another question. Good luck!